# NAT Forwarding and DNS

Tags: dns, firewall, nat

I’m new to Linux but as part of a commercial project I need to configure the firewall to redirect via NAT and DNS.

For example, I have traffic going to `www.A_DOMAIN.com:9000` (DNS translates to my server) and redirect to `hw.ANOTHER_DOMAIN.io:9998`

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Pete

Answer (score 0):

With DNS, you could make `www.A_DOMAIN.com` an alias of `hw.ANOTHER_DOMAIN.io`, but that would do nothing at all to the port number. So unless this service is something other than regular HTTP/HTTPS, DNS trickery won't do what you need.

---

You could set up a firewall DNAT rule that will accept incoming traffic at port 9000 of your server. The rule would change the addressing from `original_client:some port -> your_server's_IP:9000` to `your_server's_IP:some port -> other_server's_IP:9998` and would also automatically do the reverse mapping for any answers, so that for the original client, it would seem like the answer was coming from where the client sent the query. In the level of TCP protocol, that is rather important for the answer to be recognized as part of the original connection.

But simple firewall rules won't do anything for the requests themselves, so if you're using HTTP, the `hw.ANOTHER_DOMAIN.io` server will see that the request is still addressed to `www.A_DOMAIN.com` and might or might not respond with an error message saying effectively "I'm `hw.ANOTHER_DOMAIN.io`, I don't know anything about `www.A_DOMAIN.com`". Likewise, the client's web browser might also display a warning about the server's hostname not matching what the client thought it was requesting.

And if an TLS-secured connection (e.g. HTTPS) is used, the client will **definitely** notice that the certificate of the server that's producing the answer does not match the address of what the client was requesting, and will display a big scary warning for sure.

---

A more high-level approach would be to set up a reverse proxy at `www.A_DOMAIN.com:9000` that would re-submit any incoming requests to `hw.ANOTHER_DOMAIN.io:9998`, modifying protocol headers and decrypting & re-encrypting packets as necessary.

From the available options, this is the solution that will most seamlessly make it seem like the contents of hw.ANOTHER_DOMAIN.io:9998 is present at www.A_DOMAIN.com:9000, but this will also require the most processing power from your server.

---

If you don't care that the client will actually see that the connection is getting redirected to `hw.ANOTHER_DOMAIN.io:9998`, then there is one more possibility for HTTP/HTTPS: you can set up a small web server in `www.A_DOMAIN.com:9000` that will just reply to all requests with a redirect to a corresponding URL at `hw.ANOTHER_DOMAIN.io:9998`. Basically, just telling the web browser to "go to hw.ANOTHER_DOMAIN.io:9998 instead".

This will often mean that the client will make just one request to your server, and all the subsequent requests directly to the other server, so it is probably the most efficient solution for HTTP/HTTPS. But the client will see that the address in the web browser's address bar gets updated to `hw.ANOTHER_DOMAIN.io:9998` so this will not be the solution for you if you wish to keep the forwarding a secret. It also will not work at all if the client cannot directly connect to `hw.ANOTHER_DOMAIN.io:9998`.

---

As you can see, there are several solutions that might or might not be applicable depending on various details of your use case. Each solution has its own limitations, which may or may not be important to you.

The way your question is currently posed, there is actually nothing Unix/Linux specific in the question. You could do all the solutions I've outlined in Windows if you wanted; if TCP-level NAT is applicable to your problem, you could do it in an enterprise network router or hardware firewall device without using any server at all. You perhaps have a Linux server, but you did not specify the name and version of your distribution, so giving exact advice will be difficult. Your question is currently at risk of starting to get close votes of the "needs more focus" type.

And, if I may say so, the fact that you even have to ask a question in such an unfocused way suggests that you are perhaps not only new to Linux, but possibly also to TCP/IP networking in general. If you are indeed doing a commercial project, then you may not have the time to learn enough to even start asking the right questions about your own environment: *I think you should recognize your current limits and get help from someone in your organization that can understand your specific situation at a more technical level, if possible.*

It seems to me you would need some sort of "fundamentals of IP networking" course in order to develop a basic understanding of what technologies like DNS, firewalls and reverse proxies are and what they can and cannot do. Such a foundational knowledge is *essential* in order for you to be able to evaluate different solutions and understand what is applicable to a specific problem and what isn't.